# Python, version fragmentation and graphics...advice?

Tags: python, graphics, version

I've been working on learning python (mostly 3.1) for the last month or two.  I'm currently working on a multiplayer network enabled boardgame (Spacehulk if anyone cares) as a learning exercise and to play with my friends.

But I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall trying to find a graphics package that meets my needs.  Tkinter is available for 3.1 but I find myself needing functions from PIL, which isn't.  I've been trying to get Pygame working in 3.1 (I found a guide to) but i've been having trouble getting all the dependencies together.

So, advice?  Should I just give up on 3.1 and work in 2.7?  Anyone have a suggestion for a more robust but not too advanced graphics package for 3.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading to Python 2.7 seems to be a good option: many libraries are still not available on Python 3.

[Pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) can help you manage those two Python versions.